# Draw Sierpinski triangle with color at each depth recursively?

Tags: python, recursion, turtle-graphics

```
import turtle
w=turtle.Screen()

def Tri(t, order, size):

    if order==0:
        t.forward(size)
        t.left(120)
        t.forward(size)
        t.left(120)
        t.forward(size)
        t.left(120)

    else:
        t.pencolor('red')
        Tri(t, order-1, size/2, color-1)
        t.fd(size/2)
        t.pencolor('blue')
        Tri(t, order-1, size/2, color-1)
        t.fd(size/2)
        t.lt(120)
        t.fd(size)
        t.lt(120)
        t.fd(size/2)
        t.lt(120)
        t.pencolor('green')
        Tri(t, order-1, size/2,color-1)
        t.rt(120)
        t.fd(size/2)
        t.lt(120)
```

Can anyone help with this problem ?
I want to a sierpinski triangle that have color at specific depth
like this:

[image]

I don't know how to make the the triangle color change at specific depth.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

I think you've almost solved this already. I see your recursive calls are already trying to pass a `color` value to each lower level of the recursion. All you need to do to get it working is add that as an extra parameter to your function and make your color changing commands conditional on it being zero (indicating that you've descended to the specified level).

In python-like pseudocode:

```
def Tri(t, order, size, color):
    if order == 0:
         # draw a triangle (maybe doing coloring of the sides if color == 0 too?)

    else:
         if color == 0:
             # set first color

         Tri(t, order-1, size/2, color-1)

         if color == 0:
             # set second color

         # move to next position

         Tri(t, order-1, size/2, color-1)

         if color == 0:
             # set third color

         # move to next position

         Tri(t, order-1, size/2, color-1)

         # move to end position
```

There may be some other minor issues to work out, like making sure your movement commands don't end up recoloring some of the edges of your triangles after they've been drawn properly. It's been a long time since I've done Turtle graphics, so I'll have to leave the details to you.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the most concise way I was able to come up with

```
angles = [0, 120, 240]
colors = ["red", "blue", "magenta"]

def draw_equi_triang(t, size):
    for i in range(3):
        t.forward(size)
        t.left(120)

def shift_turtle(t, size, angle):

    # moves turtle to correct location to begin next triangle

    t.left(angle)
    t.penup()
    t.forward(size)
    t.pendown()
    t.right(angle)

def sierpinski(t, order, size, colorChangeDepth = -1):

    # draw an equilateral triangle at order 0

    if order == 0:
        draw_equi_triang(t, size)

    # otherwise, test if colorChangeDepth == 0 and when it does change the color

    else:
        if colorChangeDepth == 0:
            # get index of angles
            for (ind, angle) in enumerate (angles):
                t.color(colors[ind])
                sierpinski(t, order-1, size/2, colorChangeDepth-1)
                shift_turtle(t, size/2, angle)
        # if colorChangeDepth does not == 0 yet
        else:
            for angle in angles:
                sierpinksi(t, order-1, size/2, colorChangeDepth-1)
                shift_turtle(t, size/2, angle)
```